# Run my Python code in sublime text3 and in IDLE,But the results are not the same

Tags: python

I want to check whether a file exists using Python, `C:/test/UpdatePackage/filelist` is an existing file.

When run in sublime text 3, the result is wrong:

```
>>> f = "C:/test/UpdatePackage/filelist"
>>> import os
>>> os.path.isfile(f)
False
>>>
```

But run in Python 3.4 GUI

```
Python 3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 24 2015, 22:43:06) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.

>>> f = "C:/test/UpdatePackage/filelist"
>>> import os
>>> os.path.isfile(f)
True
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

in addition to **timgeb's** answer:

I haven't tried it, but `os.path.isfile(os.path.normpath(f))` should give you the expected behaviour. use `normpath()`, then you can use either `\` or `/` as separator and your code is (more) independent from your platform or interpreter (e.g. if you get the path from user input or other sources).

Answer (score 0):

Use `f = "C:\\test\\UpdatePackage\\filelist"` In your script. I believe IDLE automagically replaces the forward slashes for you with [os.sep](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.sep), that's why it is working inside IDLE.